# How to free() an array of structs allocated by malloc()?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, malloc, free

I've been working on a project that uses structs as storage for strings. I declared a struct consists of char type members:

```
struct datastore1
{
    char name[50];
    char address[50];
    char email[50];
    char number[50];
    char idnum[50];
};
```

I'm aware that I can just do `char *name, char *address...` but let's say we specified it with max length of 50. Then on my function which uses the struct, I malloc'ed it with index size of 30:

```
struct datastore1 *dsdata = malloc(30 * sizeof(struct datastore1));
```

Supposedly I finished copying all strings into the struct by accessing each index, How should i free the allocated memory that was used after calling malloc? I tried doing `free(dsdata)` on the end of the program but I am not sure if it's the right way. Should i free each indexes individually? Please enlighten me. Thank you in advance for the feedback!

Comment: `free(dsdata)` is correct. It's actually relatively simple - each malloc should have exactly one free of the same address that the malloc returned.

Comment: I would suggest `struct datastore1 *dsdata = malloc(30 * sizeof(*dsdata));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How should i free the allocated memory that was used after calling malloc?

Consider below example,

```
struct datastore1 *obj1 = malloc(sizeof(struct datastore1));
free(obj1);
```

Here `obj1` is pointing to the block of memory of size same as size of `datastore1` in order to free you need to send the address which is allocated by `malloc`.

[image]

likewise,

```
struct datastore1 *obj2 = malloc(3 * sizeof(struct datastore1));
free(obj2);
```

`obj2` is pointing to a block of contiguous memory of size `3 * sizeof(datastore1)` you need to pass the base address to `free`

[image]

> Should i free each indexes individually?

NO, Since block of memory is allocated only once and you need to `free` exactly one time.

Let me extend it further,

```
struct datastore1 *obj3[3];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   obj3[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct datastore1));

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    free(obj3[i]);
```

Here `obj3` is array of pointer and each index is pointing to different part of memory and hence need to be freed individually.

[image]

---

**Note: For simplicity I haven't considered return value from `malloc`. Null check has to be done on `malloc` return value.**

Answer (score 1):

#### 1.

> How should I free the allocated memory that was used after calling malloc?
>
> I tried doing `free(dsdata)` on the end of the program but I am not sure if it's the right way.

`free(dsdata)` is fine, **since** you allocated the whole space by just one call to `malloc` with:

```
struct datastore1 *dsdata = malloc(30 * sizeof(struct datastore1));
```

To cite the standard (C18), 7.22.3.4 - "The malloc function" (emphasize mine):

> 7.22.3.4   The malloc function
>
> Synopsis
>
> 1
>
> ```
>  #include <stdlib.h>
>  void* malloc(size_t size);
> ```
>
> Description
>
> 2 The malloc function **allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size** and whose value is indeterminate.
>
> Returns
>
> 3 The malloc function returns either a null pointer or **a pointer to the allocated space**.

It is correct to use `free(dsdata)` because `malloc` allocated all of the required space at once and returned a pointer to the first structure variable of this array which is assigned to the pointer of `dsdata`.

The `free()` function "knows" that `dsdata` is a reference to the whole allocated space. You do not need to free each of the 30 structures of type `struct datastore1` in memory individually.

---

#### 2.

> Should I free each indexes individually?

No, you do not need and even more important you **should not** do so; this would be [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior):

Citation from the current standard (C18), 7.22.3.5/3 - "The free function" (emphasize mine):

> Otherwise, if the argument **does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function**, or if the space **has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc**, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you only used `malloc` to allocate space for an array of `datastore1` struct, so it is sufficient to just do `free(dsdata)`.

If in the struct you would have pointers and you would use `malloc` to allocate each of them, only than you would need to `free` each of them first.

Comment: ... and if one needed to free internal pointers, too, then that would still be different from freeing each *array element* individually, as the OP supposed might be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers above are correct, but to fully understand how does it work I recommend you to learn how to use `valgrind`.
To check if program released memory correctly use

```
valgrind -v --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./your-program
```

This will execute your program on valgrind's *virtual processor* and give you full feedback about used resources.

Basically operator `[]` in C programming language in array definition context causes creation of (lets say to simplify) *static* array - this means that array is included in size of structure (if defined as part of structure) or is stored on the stack (if defined in function or globally).
The `malloc` function returns address of block of data you can use. Size of this block is at least as big as you requested. When you use `free` you release this block wich in this case means all data in block pointed by this address will be released.